# Docker compose wait for spring boot app is up

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I using docker-compose in version 3.3 and I want to wait for a container with spring app is up and after that other containers with spring boot app should be started. I tried with health check but it's doesn't work. This is my docker-compose looks like:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  eureka:
    build: ./eureka
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
    environment:
      - SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASEURL=http://zipkin:9411
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8761"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  zipkin:
    build: ./zipkin
    ports:
      - 9411:9411
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9411"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: You could create a bash (for example) script that checks the readiness-check endpoints of other containers in a loop (for example) and launches the jar only if other are started. And then you use this script as entrypoint of your spring-boot app image.

Comment: @michalk thank you for your answer, so how to pass link to zipkin container into eureka entrypoint sh script?

Comment: you can use environment variables for example. The script will pick values from the environment when then container is being launched.

Comment: This is a perfect use case for adding Kubernetes!

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) it seems that this is not possible, and they also explain why that is, while also providing some workarounds.